# LINQ Projecting relation properties with null

Tags: c#, linq

I want to select items from a table, these items have relation properties, can I projecting them if they could be nullable (ie like left join)? And if not how I can workaround this?

```
class MyProducer
{
  ....
}    

Model model = new Model();
var q = 
    model.Products
    .Select(
      p => 
        new 
        { 
            id = p.Id, 
            producer = p.Producer != null ? new MyProducer { id = p.Producer.Id } : null 
        });

var r = q.ToArray();
```

When I execute this code I have exception

> Unable to create a null constant value of type 'MyProducer'.  Only
>   entity types, enumeration types or primitive types are supported in
>   this context.

Comment: @All : Looking more closely at the error, I suspect it's somewhere else entirely. Note it says `null constant value` and I don't see anything to do with constants here.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use left join?

```
using(var model = new Model())
{
    var q = 
    from product in model.Products
    join producer in model.Producers.DefaultIfEmpty()
    on product.ProducerId equals producer.Id
    select new
    {
        Id = product.Id,
        Producer = producer != null ? new MyProducer{ Id = producer.Id} : null
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm trying to build something like mapping between LINQ entyities and my models, in the case of left join it would be ugly. As you can see 2 rows of original code turn out 5+ rows of left join. This unpleasant from point of code readability.

Comment: @baio, if you want to reduce the number of lines just put the anonymous type initializer on a single line `select new { Id = product.Id, Producer = producer != null ? new MyProducer{ Id = producer.Id } : null }`

Comment: Ok I understand that you meant to say, but actually this is just example of code, the real one is written in specific manner and I wouldn't want to refuse from it, if it is possible.

Answer (score 0):

You need to cast your `null` to `Struct`:

```
Model model = new Model(); 
var q = model.Products.Select(p => new { id = p.Id, producer =  
    p.Producer != null ? new Struct { id = p.Producer.Id } : (Struct)null });
```

Comment: Sorry "Struct" is a bad name for class, actually Struct is class.

Comment: Just guessing. Try `default(Struct)` instead of `(Struct)null`.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the only way to handle the projection of a possibly null relationship but this is how I have done it in the past. You create your new object and then when setting your properties check for null appropriately. The only problem with this solution is that you now have to check if the 'id' property of 'producer' is '0' to know if the relationship was null. If there is a better way of handling this I would love it if someone would post it here.

```
var q = 
    model.Products
    .Select(p => new 
        { 
            id = p.Id, 
            producer = new MyProducer 
            { 
               id = p.Producer == null ? 0 : p.Producer.Id
            }
        }
     );

var r = q.ToArray();
```